# Missing dependency. Vaadin, Maven

Tags: maven, vaadin

I'm trying to generate a new Vaadin project with Maven.

Using the following script to generate the project.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application \
   -DarchetypeVersion=7.5.2 \
   -DgroupId=com.example \
   -DartifactId=MvnVaadinProject \
   -Dversion=1.0 \
   -Dpackaging=war
```

When I type `mvn install` I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.5.2:compile': Unable to load the mojo 'com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.5.2:compile' in the plugin 'com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/util/scan/InclusionScanException
org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.util.scan.InclusionScanException
```

Browsing into .m2 I didn't find the folder `org/codehaus/plexus/compiler`.

Is it supposed that Maven install this dependency in any other place?

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @henri-kerola 'Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-14)'

Comment: you are using too old maven version. Try with newer one..

Comment: done but I still get the same error. It seems that one dependency is corrupt, I removed the folder from .m2 without success.

Comment: Add this       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
if that does not help post pom.xml file